# Error - couldn't find "libMyGame.so"

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

I'am tring to run MyGame cocos's program.

But when I am tring to run it on android studio get an error :

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.cocos2dx.SimpleGame-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.cocos2dx.SimpleGame-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libMyGame.so"
```

I read somewhere that before running the program on android studio i need to run the command from the game directory :

```
cocos compile -p android --android-studio
```

but then I am getting an error :

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT not defined. Please define it in your environment.
```

What i need to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Find Setup.py (python script) from root folder of cocos2dx and run it .
and give information of 
**ANDROID_SDK** - , 
**NDK** ,
**ANT**

FOR FURTHER INFORMATION FOLLOW THIS LINK [COCOS2DX - ANDROID SETUP](http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/installation/Android-terminal/)

Answer (score 0):

Define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT in environment variable of your system.

```
Variable Name : ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
Variable Value : location of your sdk
```